# vagrant/puppet: vhost "website not available"

Tags: vagrant, vhosts, puphpet

so I'm using vagrant across a couple of macs and PCs for local development.

The vhosts in `puphpet/config.yaml` look like this

```
        piYyhCPLFha4:
            servername: iamsumit.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.iamsumit.dev
            docroot: /var/www/iamsumit/dist
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''

        piYyhCPLFha5:
            servername: relocation.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.relocation.dev
            docroot: /var/www/moovel/relocation-app/dist
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''

        piYyhCPLFha7:
            servername: einzl.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.einzl.dev
            docroot: /var/www/einzl/dist
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
```

Now my problem is, that I can't get the middle vhost `relocation.dev` to work on a specific mac (works perfect on all other machines).

The other vhosts are working perfectly. It's just that one vhost that won't work. The browser will just load very long and then show me a "website unavailable" message.

This is my hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.56.102 einzl.dev
192.168.56.102 boss.dev
192.168.56.102 iamsumit.dev
192.168.56.102 relocation.dev
192.168.56.102 nephalem.dev
192.168.56.102 polygoncreator.dev
192.168.56.102 car2clean.dev
192.168.56.102 elearning.dev
```

The docroot is correct. I can't imagine what is causing puphpet/vagrant to not recognize this one vhost.
What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: What contains apache's error log for this site?

Comment: Inside your virtual machine. Probably it will be in: /var/log/apache2/piYyhCPLFha5-error.log

Comment: that file is empty. `...5-access.log` has 3 of these lines:
`192.168.56.1 - - [14/Apr/2015:09:55:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 228 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research, I found that these two lines (a necessary redirect) in the `.htaccess` file caused the page to not load anymore:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And why? Because the subdomain `www.relocation.dev` wasn't in my hosts file.
Host file line should look like this:

```
192.168.56.102 relocation.dev www.relocation.dev
```

Now everything is working fine.

Thanks @v2p for your time.